# Enable hiding navbar on iOS on scroll with body, html height = 100%

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css, iphone

I was having an issue with iOS Safari in which a select tag within a modal would scroll the element behind it.  To resolve the bug, I ended up making the following change:

```
html, body {
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}
```

This solves the problem, but has the unfortunate side effect of always showing the iOS navigation bar, even when the user scrolls down.  Is there any way to mimic the original behavior of hiding the navigation bar when a user scrolls down, and then popping it back up when they scroll up?

Thanks for your help!